# How to make a specific file always visible on the sidebar everytime I open sublime text 3

Tags: sublimetext2, sublimetext3

I switched from Notepad++ to Sublime Text 3 last week and I'm loving it. I know Notepad++ don't have a feature like this also, but is there a plugin or setting on Sublime Text 3 that I can use to make a file always visible on my sidebar every time I open it? I have a single text file that has some login info and useful note for my development and I want Sublime to remember to at least add a shortcut on that file on my sidebar so that I can access it anytime I want to.

[image: Sublime text 3]

I want **workdocs.php** to be always visible on my sidebar when every I open my Sublime Text 3. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not exactly what you want but you could try Sublime FavoriteFiles:

https://github.com/facelessuser/FavoriteFiles

It's ST3 compatible and works well. You can assign keyboard short-cuts to the various commands or use Control + Shift + P to access them quickly.